# standard deviation of any sized array java

Tags: java, arrays, math, methods

How to calculate the standard divination of an array in Java? As you can see I have already calculated the mean, and I know that at the end I will have to divide by the sample size minus 1 (n-1) and square that number. The problem I'm having is how to take every number and calculate how far it is away from the mean, then square that number. I know I could do every number from the data set separately but there has to be an easier way. Any help would be appreciated, here's my code.

```
public class CalculateArray
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int [] numbers = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

        int sum = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int min = numbers[0];
        double sd = 0;
    
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + numbers[i];
        }

        double average = sum / numbers.length;

        System.out.println("Average value is : " + average);

        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
        {
            if(numbers[i] > max)
            {
                max = numbers[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("max number is : " + max);

        for(int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++)
        {
            if(numbers[i] < min)
            {
                min = numbers[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("min number is : " + min);

        for (int i=0; i<numbers.length;i++)
        {
           //this is where im having problems
           sd = ???
        }

        double standardDeviation = math.sqrt(sd/(numbers.length-1));

        System.out.println("The standard deviation is : " + standardDeviation);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `std += pow(average - numbers[i], 2);`?

Answer (score 8):

To calculate how far a number is from the mean you use the `-` operator. For calculating the square you can use `Math.pow`. So, given that you have already calculated the `average` earlier in the program:

```
for (int i=0; i<numbers.length;i++)
{
    sd = sd + Math.pow(numbers[i] - average, 2);
}
```

By the way, the way you calculate the mean currently is broken. You should define `sum` as double, not as `int`.

Comment: You should use `Math.abs(numbers[i] - average)`, otherwise it generate negetive number when `number[i]<avarage`.

Comment: @Quoi, you don't need to calculate the absolute value. a² = |a|².

Comment: And at the end you'll want to divide the sum of the squared deviations by the number of datapoints.  I think that is a root mean square;  in the terms above,  rms = sd / numbers.length

Comment: according to [http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation-formulas.html](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation-formulas.html)

Comment: @Quoi `Math.pow(ANYTHING,2);` will **always** be positive so is redundant to use `Math.abs`

Comment: yap you are right and also +1 from me but how do I get square of negative number if required?

Comment: @Quoi Just like the square of a positive number. It's just that the result will be positive no matter the sign of the input.

Comment: Why do you say "divide by the sample size minus 1 (n-1)" - why  not divide by n?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the two pass algorithm described by others (calculate mean in the first pass and std dev in the next) please see [this link](http://www.strchr.com/standard_deviation_in_one_pass) for an example of how it can be done in a single pass. The algorithm is as follows:

```
double std_dev2(double a[], int n) {
    if(n == 0)
        return 0.0;
    double sum = 0;
    double sq_sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
       sum += a[i];
       sq_sum += a[i] * a[i];
    }
    double mean = sum / n;
    double variance = sq_sum / n - mean * mean;
    return sqrt(variance);
}
```

---

**UPDATE**
Don't do this. As Joni explains in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839056/standard-deviation-of-any-sized-array-java/14839593#comment20832614_14839593) below there is a high risk of error when implementing this is a computer program. For a stable online algorithm, Joni directs us to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm)  Wikipedia article, which as mentioned has been thoroughly analyzed.

Comment: A horrible algorithm, should never be used. For why it's bad and what alternatives exist see http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/09/26/comparing-three-methods-of-computing-standard-deviation/

Comment: @Joni thanks for the input. Is this basically an overflow error?

Comment: The problem is mainly with `sq_sum / n - mean * mean`: it calculates the difference of two large nearly equal numbers. The cancellation of digits means that the relative error goes up the roof - you may even end up with a negative variance. Wikipedia has a pretty decent page about this type of numerical problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance

Comment: Thanks @Joni, I need to learn to not believe everything I read on internet. I am updating my answer with your comment

Comment: Well, to the credit of your source, they do warn you: "Unfortunately, the result will be inaccurate when the array contains large numbers". There is a better behaved 1-pass algorithm though: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm

Comment: Perhaps I should also read on the internet more carefully. I sort of remembered that there is a single pass algorithm and posted what could find. Seems I did no search thoroughly enough, usually I check wikipedia first but didn't do a thorough job this time.

Answer (score 0):

```
k + k = 2k
```

to get the average, divide `2k` by the number of terms you have.
So the average of the terms is k. :D